# How to replace a whole observation working on a SAS file through IML

Tags: database, sas, sas-iml

Long time user, first time poster. I am very new to IML and have played around in R before. I am currently trying to create an adjacency list for easier computation of networks in SAS/IML. The file i am working on is huge. I am doing an implementation that involve using a SASfile and not have the adjacency list in memory. Creating an empty file and reading from specific rows (which corresponds to particular agents) all goes well until the "final" step: updating the entire observation.

Below is IML code that works, up until the last stage.

```
    proc iml;
    /* initialize vars*/
    checkObs = 2;
    numCol = 5;
    db = "myTestDataBase";
    nObs = 5;
    temp = {};
    myList = J(1, numCol, 0);
    nVarToUpdate = 2;

    /* create empty database */
    create (db) from myList;
        append from myList;
    close (db);
    do i = 1 to (nObs-1);
        edit (db);
            append from myList;
        close (db);
    end;

    /* read index checkObs and write to temp*/
    edit (db);
        read point (checkObs) into temp; /* Read an entire row*/
        temp[nVarToUpdate] = 1; /* I would like to update some values*/
        /* I want to replace point chekObs with the whole of vector temp*/
        replace point checkObs var _all_;
    close (db);
    print temp;
```

My aim is to replace/update a whole observation (row), while keeping the order of the rows intact. Any ideas?

Comment: On my iphone: the solution i see is having col1 as an index, delete the rows i am updating, and append the new observation at the end of the file. I can chunk these a bit to keep the disk happy.

Comment: I don't know much IML but the only way I could get it work is assign then variable COL2=1;  I'm looking into how to know the names of the variables.  Of course you have default names (COL1=COLn) but I think you will want a more general solution.

Comment: Yes, its the names of the columns that - for this particular data set with its pre-destined structure - is problematic. I need to calculate where to put the next piece of information for each addition piece of data. I have tired macro variables to  create dynamic "names" for the columns , but I cannot update it "on the fly". as it seems to compile Before running the code.

Comment: Knowing the variable names is easy (I show it in my solution, though I don't make use of it).  Unfortunately just like in base SAS you can't get that variable name into the left side of an equal sign, as far as I know...  I don't know why REPLACE doesn't take another argument which is the matrix/etc. that is desired to supply values to those variables, it seems very clunky to expect the variable names to be the same, but ...

Comment: @JonasForsman Your initial comment's solution does sound reasonable, and might be the easiest way to do this if you can't make it easily work with the macro solution.  `point` access to an on-disk file isn't terribly efficient anyway, so you don't lose too terribly much.  However, a major word of caution: the delete is *probably* a logical delete, not a physical one, so the space is probably not freed up.  This is good from a time-used point of view, but it does mean that if you do a lot of these, your file will grow in size, since it's not freeing the deleted space.

Comment: Thank you again! And i will check how the delete works so the server is happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joe's solution will work for this problem, but combining macro and IML in that way is like kissing your sister: it's not pleasant and people will look at you strangely. Joe had the right idea to get the name of the variables, but he forgot that [you can use the VALSET call to perform indirect assignment](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/03/23/indirect-assignment-how-to-create-and-use-matrices-named-x1-x2-xn.html). In other words, by having the name of a variable, you can change it's value.

If you want to avoid the macro, you can get the names of the variables one time (outside the EDIT loop) and then loop over the names of the variales, like this:

```
/* get column names ONE TIME */
use (db);
   read next var _ALL_ into temp[colname=varNames]; /* get names of cols */
close (db);

/* read index checkObs and write to temp*/
edit (db);
read point (checkObs) into temp; /* Read an entire row*/
temp[nVarToUpdate] = 1; /* I would like to update some values*/
do i = 1 to ncol(temp);
   call valset(varNames[i], temp[i]); /* update scalar variables */
end;
replace point (checkObs) var _all_;
close (db);
```

The main advantage of this technique is that you can discover the variable names at run time.

Be aware that this method (creating variable names) can be dangerous because if the data set has a variable named X, you are overwriting any pre-existing variable of that name in your program.

Also be aware that using EDIT and READ POINT on a huge data set to change one row at a time will be slower than molasses flowing uphill in the winter time.  If possible, you should [read in a big block of data](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/01/21/reading-big-data.html), operate on all rows in that block, and write out the block.

If disk space allows, you might want to try using the SETIN and SETOUT statements to [read from one data set while writing to another](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/09/17/read-one-write-another.html).  That would 
completely eliminate the need for the REPLACE statement and the VALSET call.  In general, it is more efficient to open a data set read-only and process it sequentially than to open it read/write and process it by using random access.

Comment: I am truly thankful for your answer, rick. Very elegant solution and I am happy that "new eyes" looked at the problem I have. I will read up on reading and writing larger "chunks" of the file for i/o as I have noticed the runtime of the current solutions. Again - thank you for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Great answer, something I assumed must be possible but couldn't see.  And, to forget something implies one must have learned it in the first place...

Comment: I would love to know though why REPLACE doesn't take the matrices/vectors to use as an argument, though - the above is a great solution, but still clunkier than being able to say  `replace point (checkobs) var _all_ matrix temp;` (which maps temp columns 1:1 to variables) or (`replace point(checkobs) var _all_ vnames temp_varnames;` where `temp_varnames` has two columns, one the varnames and two the vector to map over...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this, from [the documentation for `REPLACE`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/65547/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_langref_sect342.htm):

> The REPLACE statement replaces the values of observations in a SAS data set with current values of matrices with the same name.

So this would work:

```
edit (db);
    read point (checkObs) into temp; /* Read an entire row*/
    col2 = 1; /* I would like to update some values*/
    /* I want to replace point chekObs with the whole of vector temp*/
    replace point (checkObs) var('col2');
close (db);
```

Of course, that probably isn't what you had in mind.

I don't know if there's an IML way to do this - perhaps Rick will happen along and have an answer.  I'm not sure why there wouldn't be, but I am nowhere near an expert in IML, so perhaps there is - or is a reason why not.  My feeling is that what you're trying to do might be better done in an entirely different way; it's not clear exactly what you're doing, though.  If you're doing a neural network or similar, there's a lot of code out there - another approach might present itself.  I find that people coming to SAS from other languages often expect what worked in another language to work here - when there's an entirely different way to do it in SAS efficiently (which works well, if not better - just need to realize what it is).

Anyway, you can do this with a bit of setup and the macro language.  Here is an example.  You'll have to do the setup ahead of time - and if you have dynamic variable lists, this may be complicated (you may have to have a double-resolved macro variable name, for example).

The main thing to remember with the macro approach is that the macro values have to entirely be available before IML runs; so you can't put a variable in the argument, it has to be a hard-coded value or a macro variable which itself is known before IML runs.  DOSUBL/RUN_MACRO might let you get around this to some extent, but it's probably going to be complicated to do things that way.

```
proc sql;
  select name into :namelist separated by ','
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname='WORK' and memname='MYTESTDATABASE';
quit;

%macro replace_var(num_Vars=1);
        %do _i = 1 %to &num_vars.;
          %let _var = %scan(%bquote(&namelist),&_i,%str(,));
          &_var. = temp[&_i.];
        %end;
%mend;

proc iml;
    /* initialize vars*/
    checkObs = 4;
    numCol = 5;
    db = "myTestDataBase";
    nObs = 5;
    temp = {};
    myList = J(1, numCol, 0);
    nVarToUpdate = 2;

    /* create empty database */
    create (db) from myList;
        append from myList;
    close (db);

    do i = 2 to (nObs);
        edit (db);
            append from myList;
        close (db);
    end;
    /* read index checkObs and write to temp*/
    edit (db);
        read point (checkObs) into temp[colname=temp_names]; /* Read an entire row*/
        temp[nVarToUpdate] = 1; /* I would like to update some values*/
        %replace_var(num_vars=&sqlobs.);   *call the macro which sets the various variable names to their values.  Semicolon is just for syntax coloring to work.;
        /* I want to replace point chekObs with the whole of vector temp*/
        replace point (checkObs) var _all_;
    close (db);
    print temp;
    print temp_names;
  quit;
```

Comment: One note here: it seems very _easy_ to do this if you have one column/many rows, as opposed to one row/many columns.  If you stored everything in in a transposed fashion (so your `temp` vector held one column, not one row), then you could name your variables in a predictable fashion and perhaps more easily do this.  I say perhaps as I still don't know what you're really doing...

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much! Spent like 8-10 hours trying different solutions!